# The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 inside Windows Server 2008. But when I tried to start the "SQL Server Browser" service, I got the following error:

> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

So what might be causing this error?

Comment: no i do not think so.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try to open Services Window, by writing `services.msc` into **Start->Run** and hit **Enter**.

When window appears, then **find SQL Browser service**, **right click** and **choose Properties**, and then in dropdown list **choose Automatic, or Manual**, whatever you want, and **click OK**. Eventually, if not started immediately, you can again press **right click on this service** and **click Start**.

Comment: there is no "SQL Browser service" file in my pc

Answer (score 3):

This error can occur on anything that requires elevated privileges in Windows.

It happens when the "Application Information" service is disabled in Windows services.  There are a few viruses that use this as an attack vector to prevent people from removing the virus.  It also prevents people from installing software to remove viruses.

The normal way to fix this would be to run services.msc, or to go into Administrative Tools and run "Services".  However, you will not be able to do that if the "Application Information" service is disabled.

Instead, reboot your computer into Safe Mode (reboot and press F8 until the Windows boot menu appears, select Safe Mode with Networking). Then run services.msc and look for services that are designated as "Disabled" in the Startup Type column.  Change these "Disabled" services to "Automatic".

Make sure the "**Application Information**" service is set to a Startup Type of "Automatic".

When you are done enabling your services, click Ok at the bottom of the tool and reboot your computer back into normal mode. The problem should be resolved when Windows reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, the issue for me was I was trying to open 2012 SQL Server Integration Services on SSMS 2008 R2. When I opened the same in SSMS 2012, it connected right away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with RSAT installation today. I just enabled windows updates. Then I was able to install it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

**For C# COM Exception**

I know the question is for SQL but I literally couldn't find any other thread and I just want anyone in the future that stumbles upon this exception to find a solution.

It's exactly what the exception is saying. **Whatever service you're accessing is disabled, you have to change the startup mode**.

I was trying to reach the WMI through a `ManagementObjectSearcher` but it kept throwing this exception, it worked on some machines and it didn't on others.

I made it change the startup mode for the `Winmgmt` service in case it was disabled using [this code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5742574/13129943) check the blog linked in the answer to get the full code.

Answer (score 0):

For my issue the `seclogon` service was set to disabled by GPO.  This was resolved after setting this service to Automatic and starting.