# Change service start type on a remote machine

Tags: vb.net, servicecontroller

I can get the current start type of a service on a remote machine but I cannot change it. The ServiceController.StartType property is read-only.

```
Imports System.ServiceProcess

Dim myController As ServiceController
myController = New ServiceController With {
        .MachineName = "hostname",
        .ServiceName = "servicename"
        }

If .StartType.Equals(ServiceStartMode.Automatic) Then
        txtStartTypeSDM1.Text = "AUTOMATIC"
End If
myController.Close()
```

[This](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7665/Extend-ServiceController-class-to-change-the-Start) guy managed to extend the ServiceController Class that enables changing the StartUpType but it only works locally. The new Class accepts the .MachineName property but I think its broken as it cannot find the specified ServiceName.

Comment: There is this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477618/how-do-i-change-a-windows-services-startup-type-in-net-post-install) that points to using the Win32 API

Comment: @JayV that is one of the question here that I looked into and it will only work if the service is on the local machine.