# Disabling service in registry still does not prevent starting it

Tags: c#, windows, service

I would like to disable service programmatically through registry. To do that, I modify the following registry key : `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\SensorDataService\Start`, where I set its value 0x4 which corresponds to disabled state. Now, when I check service in Windows Service Manager - it's reported as disabled and I can't start it.[image]

However, if I try to have it started programmatically like this:

```
var serviceController = new ServiceController("SensorDataService");
        try
        {
            serviceController.Start();
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Then service is started...
[image]

When I disable service through windows service UI or SC command line, then I got exception stating that can't start disabled service, exactly what I expect.

Does anyone know if setting above-mentioned value in registry is just not enough to disable the service?

Comment: Did you also try [using WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/changestartmode-method-in-class-win32-service)?

Comment: ``WMI``  will work most likely... As well as using Process.Start() routine or P/Invoke. But I'd like to avoid such approaches.

Comment: Why are you using `ControlSet001` and not `CurrentControlSet`?

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

I was able to reproduce this, and to make it work with the plain registry change for service with name "SensorDataService" as you want `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SensorDataService\Start` and then change the value to `0x4` which indeed means disabled, then you have to restart your computer and then the exception you want is thrown when you start the service from code.

## Additional info / possible other solutions

I'm using CurrentControlSet just to be sure the correct one is changed but that doesn't make any difference in the results

I tested this using *net6.0* and *net7.0*

When one changes it by hand in the Services GUI, I assume they call Service Control Manager and it changes the registry entry and also something internal like in memory cache or creates some file somewhere, if you are able to reload it maybe restart is not necessary.

I tried also checking whether it doesn't change any other registry entries via "RegistryChangesView" tool but I didn't see anything what I suspected to be a part of this

I would therefore highly recommend to achieve what you want to achieve by using the Service Control Manager here are some approaches:

1. using cmd or calling cmd from c# code:

   - sc config "SensorDataService" start= disabled
   - if using powershell:
     & sc config "SensorDataService" start= disabled
2. using WMI manually which was already mentioned in comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75173850/disabling-service-in-registry-still-does-not-prevent-starting-it#comment132654556_75173850)
3. or using something from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477618/how-do-i-change-a-windows-services-startup-type-in-net-post-install) mainly this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5742574) but adjust the code so it suits your needs, my quick example of it:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace ServiceTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static class ServiceHelper
        {
            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern Boolean ChangeServiceConfig(
                IntPtr hService,
                UInt32 nServiceType,
                UInt32 nStartType,
                UInt32 nErrorControl,
                String lpBinaryPathName,
                String lpLoadOrderGroup,
                IntPtr lpdwTagId,
                [In] char[] lpDependencies,
                String lpServiceStartName,
                String lpPassword,
                String lpDisplayName);

            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            static extern IntPtr OpenService(
                IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, uint dwDesiredAccess);

            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenSCManagerW", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(
                string machineName, string databaseName, uint dwAccess);

            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CloseServiceHandle")]
            public static extern int CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr hSCObject);

            private const uint SERVICE_NO_CHANGE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            private const uint SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG = 0x00000001;
            private const uint SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG = 0x00000002;
            private const uint SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS = 0x000F003F;

            public static void ChangeStartMode(ServiceController svc, ServiceStartMode mode)
            {
                var scManagerHandle = OpenSCManager(null, null, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
                if (scManagerHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    throw new ExternalException("Open Service Manager Error");
                }

                var serviceHandle = OpenService(
                    scManagerHandle,
                    svc.ServiceName,
                    SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG | SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG);

                if (serviceHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    throw new ExternalException("Open Service Error");
                }

                var result = ChangeServiceConfig(
                    serviceHandle,
                    SERVICE_NO_CHANGE,
                    (uint)mode,
                    SERVICE_NO_CHANGE,
                    null,
                    null,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

                if (result == false)
                {
                    int nError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    var win32Exception = new Win32Exception(nError);
                    throw new ExternalException("Could not change service start type: "
                        + win32Exception.Message);
                }

                CloseServiceHandle(serviceHandle);
                CloseServiceHandle(scManagerHandle);
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceController = new ServiceController("SensorDataService");
            ServiceHelper.ChangeStartMode(serviceController, ServiceStartMode.Disabled);
            Console.WriteLine("Service disabled");
            serviceController.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Service started");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contribution, appreciate it. However, we're still left with choice of either using unmanaged API or command line/WMI. While it can be used - I'm more looking into finding standard way of doing this.